# VBA Paste values - Response time

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that copies one range to another

```
rng1.Copy Destination:=rng2
```

However I only want the values, not all the formatting, so I have the below which works to achieve this

```
rng1.Copy
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However, the processing speed of this is painfully slow. The sheet grinds to a halt for quite a long time compared to the instant response of the 1st formula.

Is there a method of amending the 1st formula to paste values only? I was unable to find a way in similar questions about pasting values....

Alternatively, is there another method that is quicker than using the 2nd formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy & paste is notoriously slow in VBA, better to just assign directly, assuming both ranges are the same size

`rng2.value = rng1.value`